# Error when running OpenMPI based library

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, openmpi

I have install openmpi library from the standard apt-get install available in Ubuntu. I run a python code which call MPI libraries. I get the following error. Any ideas whatis the source of error? Is it an OpenMPI configuration error? How to fix this?

```
[thebigbang:17162] mca: base: component_find: unable to open /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_paffinity_hwloc: perhaps a missing symbol, or compiled for a different version of Open MPI? (ignored)
[thebigbang:17162] mca: base: component_find: unable to open /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_carto_auto_detect: perhaps a missing symbol, or compiled for a different version of Open MPI? (ignored)
[thebigbang:17162] mca: base: component_find: unable to open /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_carto_file: perhaps a missing symbol, or compiled for a different version of Open MPI? (ignored)
[thebigbang:17162] mca: base: component_find: unable to open /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_shmem_mmap: perhaps a missing symbol, or compiled for a different version of Open MPI? (ignored)
[thebigbang:17162] mca: base: component_find: unable to open /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_shmem_posix: perhaps a missing symbol, or compiled for a different version of Open MPI? (ignored)
[thebigbang:17162] mca: base: component_find: unable to open /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_shmem_sysv: perhaps a missing symbol, or compiled for a different version of Open MPI? (ignored)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
It looks like opal_init failed for some reason; your parallel process is
likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process can
fail during opal_init; some of which are due to configuration or
environment problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure;
here's some additional information (which may only be relevant to an
Open MPI developer):



     opal_shmem_base_select failed
      --> Returned value -1 instead of OPAL_SUCCESS

--------------------------------------------------------------------------

[thebigbang:17162] [[INVALID],INVALID] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Error in file runtime/orte_init.c at line 79

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
It looks like MPI_INIT failed for some reason; your parallel process is
likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process can
fail during MPI_INIT; some of which are due to configuration or environment
problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure; here's some
additional information (which may only be relevant to an Open MPI
developer):



    ompi_mpi_init: orte_init failed
      --> Returned "Error" (-1) instead of "Success" (0)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------

*** An error occurred in MPI_Init
*** on a NULL communicator
*** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL: your MPI job will now abort
[thebigbang:17162] Local abort before MPI_INIT completed successfully; not able to aggregate error messages, and not able to guarantee that all other processes were killed!
```

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be a somewhat complex problem with linking and how modules are loaded. The solution is to compile openmpi with `--disable-dlopen`

Compiling with `--disable-mca-dso` also worked for me. Unfortunately, I don't know how easy this is on ubuntu.

See http://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=building#avoid-dso

I found the solution here:

http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Problem-installing-Rmpi-with-Open-MPI-td4641762.html