# Error with openmpi when using pyipopt

Tags: python, c++, linux, openmpi, ipopt

I installed ipopt from source and followed all the steps and make test is successful too. But after I installed pyipopt from https://github.com/xuy/pyipopt and ran the test examples, the following error shows up:

```
[PyIPOPT] Ipopt will use Hessian approximation.

[PyIPOPT] Problem created
Going to call solve
[ 1.  5.  5.  1.]
 mca: base: component_find: unable to open /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_paffinity_hwloc: perhaps a missing symbol, or compiled for a different version of Open MPI? (ignored)
 mca: base: component_find: unable to open /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_carto_auto_detect: perhaps a missing symbol, or compiled for a different version of Open MPI? (ignored)
 mca: base: component_find: unable to open /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_carto_file: perhaps a missing symbol, or compiled for a different version of Open MPI? (ignored)
 mca: base: component_find: unable to open /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_shmem_mmap: perhaps a missing symbol, or compiled for a different version of Open MPI? (ignored)
 mca: base: component_find: unable to open /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_shmem_posix: perhaps a missing symbol, or compiled for a different version of Open MPI? (ignored)
 mca: base: component_find: unable to open /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_shmem_sysv: perhaps a missing symbol, or compiled for a different version of Open MPI? (ignored)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
It looks like opal_init failed for some reason; your parallel process is
likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process can
fail during opal_init; some of which are due to configuration or
environment problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure;
here's some additional information (which may only be relevant to an
Open MPI developer):

  opal_shmem_base_select failed
  --> Returned value -1 instead of OPAL_SUCCESS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[pengkai-SAIC-supermicro:22013] [[INVALID],INVALID] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Error in file runtime/orte_init.c at line 79
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
It looks like MPI_INIT failed for some reason; your parallel process is
likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process can
fail during MPI_INIT; some of which are due to configuration or environment
problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure; here's some
additional information (which may only be relevant to an Open MPI
developer):

  ompi_mpi_init: orte_init failed
  --> Returned "Error" (-1) instead of "Success" (0)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*** An error occurred in MPI_Init
*** on a NULL communicator
*** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL: your MPI job will now abort
 Local abort before MPI_INIT completed successfully; not able to aggregate error messages, and not able to guarantee that all other processes were killed!
```

Found a [similar error here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26901663/error-when-running-openmpi-based-library) and it uses `--disable-dlopen` to make it work, but how can I add this tag in ipopt compiling process?

Comment: At first glance, `pyipopt` does not directly depend on MPI, so i suspect `numpy` depends on Open MPI. How did you build/install Open MPI and numpy ?

Comment: I installed 'numpy' from 'apt-get' and it had been working fine coz I use it in other programs. Never really explicitly installed openmpi, I think it came with ipopt.